# Black Screen on Boot - Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

I am using a Vilros Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian. The RPi works, but every time I boot the system, nothing shows up on my monitor (resolution 2048x1080), just a black screen. I can blindly enter my credentials, then run `startx`, then the GUI shows up no problem on my monitor and everything is good.

This happens when I start the RPi with everything (keyboard, mouse, monitor) already plugged in, monitor in HDMI 0. When I boot the RPi without the monitor plugged in, then plug it in once its ready to go, I can see the boot screen/terminal, but the resolution is bad because the system used some other poorer resolution than 2K.

List of all the things I've tried (which failed):
Going into `/boot/config.txt` and setting (at different times):

- `disable_overscan=1`
- `framebuffer_width=2048`
- `framebuffer_height=1080`
- `config_hdmi_boost=4.`
- also, `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` by default from NOOBS, so that is already set.

I also tried hitting enter/typing in gibberish to the black screen, but that gave me nothing. If anyone could help me out with this problem, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thats a weird resolution. I would not use Noobs, flash 'Raspbian Buster with Desktop' direct to sd card with Etcher. More likely to detect your screen properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by running

sudo raspi-config

then using advanced options -> resolution, and setting my resolution to DMT 1920x1080p.

In /boot/config.txt, this sets:

hdmi_group=2

hdmi_mode=82

This was for a Viotek FI24D monitor which has a resolution of 2560x1440p.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.